# Strange case js mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I write simple app with expressjs and mongoose and I have strange problem.This is part of the code:

```
db.addOwner = function(obj){
var params = arguments[0],
    newOwner = Owner({
        firstName: params.firstName,
        lastName: params.lastName,
        age: params.age
    });

    newOwner
        .save()
        .then(console.log);
};

db.addCar = function(obj){
    var params = arguments[0],
        newCar = Car({
            model: params.model,
            year: params.year,
            hp: params.hp
        });

    newCar
        .save()
        .then(console.log);
};
```

The problem is that db.addOwner work but db.addCar don't.Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Try to remove `newOwner ` and `newCar` at the same var declaration of `params`.

Comment: And how do you instance Owner? I thing it's necessary `var newOwner = new Owner({});`

Comment: Make it in different declarations but still don't work.I think that var newOwner = Owner({}) is OK.newOwner works but newCar don't

Comment: some error in console?

Comment: No, nothing... :/

Comment: params in addCar has values?

Comment: Of course.This is the repository https://github.com/sgeorgiev24/carsAndOwners

Comment: Have you checked the types  coming on params? if they match the schema?